# 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

```
Player1Word = input("input word here 10 letters max")
length = (list(map(int(len, Player1Word.split()))))
print(length)
```

I have an error where I cannot set a condition in a while loop due to the length variable being a list.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is the error message and I am trying to make it so the while will not be activated if the length is equal to another variable.

```
while Player2 < 15 and hangman < 12 and rightletters < length:
```

if i remove the int() from the original code like so.

```
Player1Word = input("input word here 10 letters max")
length = (list(map(len, Player1Word.split())))
print(length)
```

The error message below is given.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Can't imagine what you are trying to do with `list(map(int(len())))` there.

Comment: I was miss-informed from another site that said that inorder to do what I wanted I need to do  list(map(len, Player1Word.split())).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing some excess computation. What you require in case you need to count the **number of words** the user inputs :

```
length = len(Player1Word.split())
```

Otherwise, if it is just for getting the **total length** of `Player1Word`, just `len` is enough.

```
length = len(Player1Word)
```

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be just `len(Player1Word)`?

Comment: Yeah you dont even need the .split()

Comment: No. I think he wants **count of words** rather than length of the input string

Comment: he says input 'word'

Comment: Why do you think that? He doesn't say so, and in any case Hangman doesn't usually deal with words separately but just with characters.

Comment: im trying to print the length of the word in letters and this method gives the amount of words inputted. Thanks anyway

Comment: @KyleODonnell Have added bit more explanation.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Comment: it says I need to wait inorder to do it -  I will mark it once its available.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `len` function to get the total length of the string.

> `len(s)`
>
> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The
>   argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or
>   range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

So, all you need to do is :

```
length = len(Player1Word)
```